# Node.JS callback post request close

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, cron, forever

Hi is there any way to close a post request in node.Js, this is how i do it and it happens every 10 seconds. i dont need the response, just need to make a call to URL only. if we use curl in linux there is a way to close as `$curl->close()`

```
function callUrl(url, data){
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    url,
    {form: {data: data}},
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

}

to deploy `node.JS` i used forever https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever
The issue i am having is, since i am a newbie i dont know why this happen, but the server keeps always a load average at 90% or above, this behavior is after running the node `app.js` with forever.

```
forever start app.js
```

is anyone had similar issues ? or how did u deploy if not used forever to deploy?

server load average is checked by typing `w`

This is how i call the function.

```
var cTask = setInterval(function() {
    var utcDate = moment.utc();

console.log('cron timer start: ' + moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));

jsonObject.startAt = tmpStartAt;
jsonObject.endAt = tmpEndAt;
data = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

callUrl(callbackUrl1, data);

if (endAt = "my time to end") {
    clearInterval(cTask);
    callUrl(callbackUrl2, data);
}
}, callback * 1000);
```

Comment: nohup ./app.js > ./stderr.app.log &

Comment: @AlexKashin what do u mean?

Comment: nohup - standard unix process wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I don't really know what value the variable callback is having. But yes an alternative for forever is the PM2 module. It  is a great handy tool for deployment and can also monitor CPU usage with pm2 monit.

Comment: callback value is means seconds, 10 seconds,  it can be 10 or 20 or 30 so each and every 10 or 20 or 30 seconds this will call the URL

Comment: Okay. Give pm2 a try it is by far the best load balancer and clustering module present in node